# Error when run query trigger in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

please help
i have trigger code below

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `mydb`.`table0`
AFTER INSERT ON `mydb`.`table0`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN    
IF (
    SELECT table1.idtable1  FROM table2, table1, table 
    WHERE table1.idtable1=table2.idtable2
    and table0.idtable0=table1.idtable1
)
THEN
    UPDATE targettable 
    SET targettable.column = 1
    WHERE targettable.idtable=table1.idtable1;
END IF;

END$$
```

after running it, it shows error

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 17

how to fix it? MySQL version is 5.5.34

Comment: SELECT table1.idtable1  FROM table2, table1, table <- should the last table be table0?

Comment: What is the trigger supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

table is a reserved word in mysql. Surround table with backticks. Also you were missing delimiter and a semicolon at the end.
This works:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `mydb`.`table0`
AFTER INSERT ON `mydb`.`table0`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN    
IF (
    SELECT table1.idtable1  FROM table2, table1, `table` 
    WHERE table1.idtable1=table2.idtable2
    and table0.idtable0=table1.idtable1
)
THEN
    UPDATE targettable 
    SET targettable.column = 1
    WHERE targettable.idtable=table1.idtable1;
END IF;
END;$$
delimiter ;
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `mydb`.`table0`
AFTER INSERT ON `mydb`.`table0`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN    
IF (
    SELECT table1.idtable1  FROM table2, table1, table <-- you should escape this using backticks as this is a reserved word i.e., `table`
    WHERE table1.idtable1=table2.idtable2
    and table0.idtable0=table1.idtable1
)
THEN
    UPDATE targettable 
    SET targettable.column = 1
    WHERE targettable.idtable=table1.idtable1;
END IF;

END$$
```